# How to make mouse hover not shift background downward? (Beginner CSS)

Tags: html, css

http://jsbin.com/wibasu/edit?html,output

As you can see, when you hover your mouse over the second row of options, the red border shifts downward even though the hover-created background doesn't extend past its borders. is there a way to make it so the bottom background doesn't shift downward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the height and margin-bottom from the :hover

```
     #topicmenu li:hover {
        background-color:#a8a8a8;
        color:black;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a margin added in hover that is causing the white space
remove this

```
#topicmenu li:hover {
    background-color: #a8a8a8;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    /*margin-bottom: 5px;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is created by two CSS rules in your styles:

```
margin-bottom: 5px;
height: 20px;
```

According to your CSS, both are ***only*** applied when you `:hover`. To fix it, move those style rules to the definition without `:hover`.

http://jsbin.com/gefepuyoca/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>navigation bar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="b.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>AboutUs</li>
        <li>stackoverflow</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}

div.navigation ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

div.navigation ul li{
    float:left;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    margin: 0.5px;
    padding:10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 50px;

}

div.navigation ul li:hover{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```